# Template parameter override not work if deploy template from storage?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to deploy my ARM template from storage blob. Following is what I did:

```
1. Upload the template file template.json and parameter file paramter.json to blob

   In the parameter file I defined a parameter with empty value:
   "environment": {
   "value":""
   }


2. Run following powershell script to deploy template and override the parameter:

   New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup
                               -TemplateUri $templateUri
                               -TemplateParameterUri $parameterUri
                               -environment "Test"
```

But per the template output, the actual environment value is empty.

It is interesting that, if I deploy the template from local file with TemplateFile and TemplateParameterFile, than it works well.

Anyone knows what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think anything is wrong with your code, its just this cmdlet is coded in such a fashion that you cannot override parameters that are set in the parameters file if you supply parameters file from the URI, unfortunately.